# block sending emails that are not from a specific domain

Tags: php, email, smtp, block

I would like to filter emails sent. Emails are sent with the PHP mail() function. I would like, without modifying any PHP file if possible, to let emails out only emails that are to a specific domain, and not others. I don't have access to the SMTP server.

Comment: how do you think this might be possible without touching any php file and without any filter in the sending mailserver? The only way would be to use some javascript but that doesn't prevent a user to kill javascript and just submit the form.

Comment: I suppose you could sit outside the hosting facility and intercept the electronic postman when he comes out with his digital bag full  of 1's and 0's and paw through them with a multimeter/oscilloscope and ground-out the ones that aren't fit to be released.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this helps someone ... If the emails are sent after a form is submitted (or similar action), you could change the action attribute of the form html element to point to a new php file that acts as a filter. Once passed (if so) you redirect to the "proper" destination to send the emails. The filtering could be something as easy as:

```
$good = "*@mydomain.foo, *@localhost";

$good = explode(',', $good);

if (pattern_grep($_POST['email'], $good)) {
   // action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to look at the associative array for the "to" field and use the php regex class to match domains that you blacklist.